# Getting all values of a form in angular2

Tags: html, angular

I can get the value of a form using the following code:

```
<input type="text" formControlName="subscriptionFormName" id="subscriptionFormName" #UserName class="form-control" mdbInputDirective>
<button class="btn btn-indigo btn-lg btn-block waves-light" type="button" (click)="OnSubmit(UserName.value)" mdbWavesEffect>Send
    <i class="fa fa-paper-plane-o ml-1"></i>
</button>
```

but what I need is to get all values of a form so I can do this:

```
<button class="btn btn-indigo btn-lg btn-block waves-light" type="button" (click)="OnSubmit(allFormValues)" mdbWavesEffect>Send
    <i class="fa fa-paper-plane-o ml-1"></i>
</button>

user: User;
ObSubmit(values) {
    user.UserName = values.UserName;
    user.Password = values.Password;
    ......
}
```

below is the whole code:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12 text-left">

    <form [formGroup]="subscriptionForm">
      <h3 style="color: gray; text-align: center;">Registration</h3>

      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <div class="md-form">
            <i class="fa fa-user prefix grey-text"></i>
            <input type="text" formControlName="UserName" id="UserName" class="form-control" mdbInputDirective>
            <label for="UserName">Your UserName</label>
          </div>
          <br>
          <div class="md-form">
            <i class="fa fa-user prefix grey-text"></i>
            <input type="text" formControlName="FirstName" id="FirstName" class="form-control" mdbInputDirective>
            <label for="FirstName">Your First name</label>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <div class="md-form">
            <i class="fa fa-user-secret prefix grey-text"></i>
            <input type="password" id="Password" formControlName="Password" class="form-control" mdbInputDirective>
            <label for="Password">Your password</label>
          </div>
          <br>
          <div class="md-form">
            <i class="fa fa-user-user prefix grey-text"></i>
            <input type="text" id="LastName" formControlName="LastName" class="form-control" mdbInputDirective>
            <label for="LastName">Your Last name</label>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <br>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <div class="md-form">
            <i class="fa fa-envelope prefix grey-text"></i>
            <input type="email" id="Email" formControlName="Email" class="form-control" mdbInputDirective>
            <label for="Email">Your Email</label>
          </div>
          <br>
          {{subscriptionForm.value|json}}
          <br>
          <div class="text-center">
            <button class="btn btn-indigo btn-lg btn-block waves-light" type="button" (click)="OnSubmit()" mdbWavesEffect>Send
              <i class="fa fa-paper-plane-o ml-1"></i>
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>

  </div>
</div>

import { User } from './../../shared/user.model';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormBuilder, Validators } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-register',
  templateUrl: './register.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./register.component.scss']
})
export class RegisterComponent implements OnInit {
  subscriptionForm: FormGroup;
  user: User;

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
    this.subscriptionForm = fb.group({
      UserName: ['', Validators.required],
      Password: ['', Validators.required],
      Email:    ['', Validators.required, Validators.email],
      FirstName: ['', Validators.required],
      LastName: ['', Validators.required]
    });
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  OnSubmit() {
   this.user = this.subscriptionForm.value;
   console.log(this.user);
  }

}
```

When I use the `#subscriptionForm="ngForm"` I get an error. Probably because of the `[formGroup]="subscriptionForm"`. I don't know what a reactive form or other forms. I'll study that after this but can you help me with this? Thank you.

Comment: Please see my edits. I don't know what's the difference.

Comment: I hope you get what I mean by the edited post.

Comment: please change name of your control similar to name in you user class and just do as I suggested you dont need to do much

Comment: Yes I get what you mean. I am going to edit my post to reflect it.

Comment: I used that but it gives me null values.

Comment: can you do this in your html `{{subscriptionForm.value|json}}` add this line see what you get

Comment: For some reason it is not showing... This is how I did it in my html. ` <br>
          {{subscriptionForm.value|json}}
          <br>`

Comment: have you entered values in your control , if yes then check your debugger console

Comment: It's weird cause in my console I do not get any errors and yes it is supposed to reflect the values in my input fields but for some reason it is not...

Comment: I made the codes a lot readable. Please see edited post.

Comment: working : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qurccv?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[Working Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qurccv?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts) based on your input in question.

Dont mix Reactive form approach with Template Driven approach, otherwise you end up will lot of problem. Follow one of them in one component. As you are following Reactive form follow that only.

that means you cannot use `#subscriptionForm="ngForm"` as its template driven form approach.

---

I suggest you make use of reactive form approach , so you can get all form value in once by doing this

```
 user = userForm.value ;
```

but for that you need to crate from by yourself and do like this

```
<form [formGroup]="userForm">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="center-block">Name:
      <input class="form-control" formControlName="name">
    </label>
  </div>
</form>
```

ts file

```
 User:user;
 constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
    this.createForm();
  }

  createForm() {
    //form control name should match with User class property name
    this.userForm= this.fb.group({
      name: ['', Validators.required ],
      street: '',
      ..other property
    });
  }

  submit() {
   this.user = userForm.value;
   //if property doesnt match then do this 
   this.user.Name = this.userForm.get('name').value;
   ..do for all property 
  }
```

Cannot explain in detail , you should follow this : https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms

Comment: I followed this but I get a null values. Please see my edit.

Comment: @stackquestions - seems issue with mdbInputDirective , as its working at stackbiz with code you given

Comment: I copied and pasted your code into mine. I still couldn't get it to work! Thank you for being so patient.

Comment: I copied and pasted the your code to mine. But I still can't get it to work. Thank you for being so patient..

Comment: @stackquestions - so it not working at all, html aslo not displaying json value ....stackbiz is working for you right ?

Comment: Thank you for the sample. I saw what I was missing. My component and forms are correct. I was missing a module in the app.module.ts!

Comment: @stackquestions -welcome ..thats y always good to have site like stackbiz where we can share code :)

Answer (score 17):

The accepted answer is outdated and does not work anymore for Angular 8+, this works nicely to get all your values:

```
for (const field in this.myForm.controls) { // 'field' is a string
  console.log(this.myForm.controls[field].value);
}
```

Comment: Why exactly does `userForm.values` not work anymore? do you have a source to confirm that?

Comment: @marcel Don't know. Source? The docs were not helping me when I faced the problem. I just figured it out with some digging in the form object.

Comment: Super update, @Michelangelo! And for those who also need the keys...

         Object.keys(this.myForm.controls).forEach((key) => {
            console.log('this key: ' + key);
            console.log(key + ' value: ' + this.myForm.get(key).value);
        });

Answer (score 2):

Super update, @Michelangelo! And for those who also need the keys...

```
     Object.keys(this.myForm.controls).forEach((key) => {
        console.log('this key: ' + key);
        console.log(key + ' value: ' + this.myForm.get(key).value);
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Use NgModel to get the data of each tag in a form 
Try  this: add  attribute to input tag `[(ngModel)]="password"`

```
Component:
password; 
password_com;

this.password_com=this.password;
```